# Notify object that something has happened - listener objects?

Tags: java, interface

I need help with some Java code. I would like to know how to notify an object that something happened. Let me explain.

I have two Person objects named "Julie" and "Matt". Julie will get a lolipop sometimes in near future, but Matt doesn't know when (neither do Julie). But Matt wants to know when Julie will get lolipop. He wants to be notified.

**Please note:**

- I'm not asking how to do this with Observable
- I need to know how to do this with my own interface or whatever is needed to acomplish this task

Please see my sketch.

[image]

Comment: The Observer pattern (or callback) is what you want. Implement it yourself or use Java's implementation.

Comment: A PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners can fit the bill as per @SotiriosDelimanolis's recommendation. Look up "bound properties" and JavaBeans.

Comment: If you're in need of a tutorial, this should give you a run-down on the basics: http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html

Comment: Straight forward answer is "Observer Pattern"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer may be to store a reference to Matt with Julie. Then, set up Julie so that she can only "receive" the lollipop via a single gateway method, such as setLollipop(boolean b).

Within this method, you can use the reference to Matt to set a flag within Matt that shows Julie received the Lollipop, or call a method on the reference to Matt to set some action going.

The act of "registering" Matt with Julie, it seems to me, is a sort of simple "Observer" design pattern but without the use of EventListeners or the Observable interface.

If I remember my patterns correctly, having a method in Julie call Matt is a "push" and having having Matt check in with Julie is a "pull" sort of notification. But I am not booked up on patterns and may have things a bit mixed up.

Comment: Don't do such things, implement the oberver pattern. its very easy and reuasble, and it's a really really really approved method!

Comment: What I described IS an implementation of the Observer pattern. How is it not? Here's the wikipedia definition: "The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods." In this case, Julie is the "subject" and Matt is a registered dependent.

Comment: when you just call a method it's not implementing the observer pattern; Observer pattern means you can have any listener added; if you call the method on 'Matt' then it's no listener... (but - i must be honest, your solution would work) - but just imagine, Julie knows another Person, how would that other Person be notified?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your concern. My thought is that adding observers is an easy refactor: Matt and anyone else to be notified can implement a common "LollipopWatcher" Interface, and that could serve as a basis for a collection held in Julie. The OP wanted a solution that was on the simple side. But I agree, if more than one observer, it is better/safer to use an Interface. If this is the OP's first acquaintance with the pattern, maybe seeing it in the simple form will help make the concept of the more general form clearer and less of a hurdle.

Comment: Wow, what you describe now is really the observer pattern! i hope you didn't feel angry when i responded, maybe i was too harsh! i'm really glad that thing turned out this was! good luck, and you seem to do the right things! keep it up!